# Metro working hours in Lille

Tags: public-transport, france, lille

I would like to get to Lille Flandres station by means of metro. However, i do not know working schedule of Lille metro.

My question is that does metro work 7/24 in Lille, France?

Answer (score 3):

The two Lille Metro lines run from approximately 5.30am to midnight daily.

You can use [Transpole's trip planner](https://www.transpole.fr/cms/institutionnel/se-deplacer/) to look up specific hours for each of the two Metro trains (click on Horaires, select M1 or M2 and your desired date and time) and other Transpole routes, and to plan a trip between two points.